# Difference between previous and current month

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to calculate the difference between current month and previous month.
The date field in my DB called `C_DATE` (dd/MM/YYYY), and I'm using in my sheet a date filter in the format: `Year(C_DATE)&'-'& Num( Month(C_DATE),'00')`. So when the user choose month (for example `2022-05`), he will see the difference in the data between May and April.
I've already tried to calculate by:

```
count ({<Answer_num={">=6"}, C_DATE={">=$(=(MonthStart(Max(C_DATE))))<=$(=(MonthEnd(Max(C_DATE))))"}>}Answer_num)  -
count ({<Answer_num={">=6"}, C_DATE={">=$(=(AddMonths( MonthStart(Max(C_DATE)),-1)))<=$(=(MonthStart(Max(C_DATE)))))"}>}Answer_num)
```

but i'm getting wrong outcome. is it maybe because of the date filter format? What can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a matter of getting the date format correct and using the proper set operator. This may work:

```
=Count({1<Answer_num={">=6"}, C_DATE={">=$(=Date(MonthStart(Max(C_DATE)), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))<=$(=Date(MonthEnd(Max(C_DATE)), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))"}>*$} Answer_num)
-
Count({1<Answer_num={">=6"}, C_DATE={">=$(=Date(AddMonths(MonthStart(Max(C_DATE)),-1), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))<=$(=Date(MonthStart(Max(C_DATE)), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))"}>*$} Answer_num)
```

This adds the `=Date(..., 'DD/MM/YYYY')` expression to the set expressions so that the formatting matches the format of the **[C_DATE]** field. We also add the `*` [set operator](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-operators.htm) so that we get the **intersection** between the selection (`$`) and our `">=...<=..."` set expression.

I'm sort of guess on the use of the intersection operator, it could be that the union operator (`+`) is the correct one to use in this case.